# Secured ASP.NET web service and php

Tags: php, asp.net

What is the best way to call a secured ASP.NET web service from PHP?

Comment: Secured in which way? Basic or digest authentication via HTTP(s)? WS-* secured?

Comment: Thanks, as my manager suggested I used one time token approach between the client and the server for each request.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `fsockopen`:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fsockopen.php

Or `Curl`:

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/curl.examples-basic.php

Or `file_get_contents`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php